# Inflating menu (actionbar) inside fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have set inside my fragment

```
 setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

I have noticed that you can add via code more buttons into the actionbar (hosted in activity) using menu.add

Is it not possible to inflate the menu from the activity and then later a menu for the fragment.

I have seen some examples of doing a menu.clear() before inflating from the fragment but this means its overriding what the activity created.

Anyone suggest the best way of handling this ?

Is using the menu.clear the right way to go and ONLY the fragment should be in charge of the menus ?

A little confused the best way of doing this and recommended way of doing this.

Thanks

Comment: I am actually hiding the menu items on onPrepareOptionsMenu
and adding menu items in onCreateOptionsMenu

I don't know is it the correct way

Answer (score 0):

I am using a different method. I add all of the buttons from the beginning. In the onSectionAttached I set a flag to true if that fragment is attached and i call invalidateOptionsMenu() (it will make onCreateOptionsMenu reload )then if the fragment is attached to the activity I set the required buttons to visible else i set them not visible